# Why does my app connect to my TCP server multiple times in my react native app?

Tags: javascript, react-native, function, tcp

When I run the code, it connects to my TCP server multiple times even though I am expecting it to connect only once

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, Component }  from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Image, Button } from 'react-native';
import { Touchable, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native-web';
var net = require('react-native-tcp-socket');
var cert= require('./certificate.pem');


export default function AssetExample() {;
    const [out, outfunc] = useState('Connecting...');
    const [count, countfunc] = useState(0);
        const client = net.createConnection(
        { port: 4242, host: '192.168.1.108', tls: true, tlsCheckValidity: false, tlsCert: cert  },
        () => {
        console.log("Connected");
        client.write("1");
        client.write("2");
        client.write("3");
        client.write("4");
        })
        client.on("data", function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            var dat = data.toString();
            countfunc(count + 1);
            outfunc(out + "\n" + dat);
            if (data == "") {
              console.log("discon");
            }
            if (dat == "ACCGNT") {
              console.log("GRANTED");
            if (dat == "ALRCON"){
                client.destroy();
            }
              
            }}); 
//            client.destroy();
        
    return (
        <View>
            <Text>{count}</Text>
          <Text>
            {out}
          </Text>
        </View>
      );

}
```

The output is also changing a lot and it does not seem to follow how I programmed it to look. The output seems to be flicking from many other outputs.

Comment: You are setting a state which will trigger a rerender of the component. The code will run again and create a new client each time. Put the code inside a `useEffect` with an empty dependency array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React triggers your function multiple times during rendering. But doesn't rerender the UI. so whatever js code inside the function will be executed every time. SO to avoid you need to move the connection logic to useEffect hook

```html
useEffect(()=>{
// establish connection 
return ()=>{ 
// destroy connection
} 
},[])
```

Now the connection will happen only once. if you to reconnect based on some state. add that state in dependency array.